# How to toggle a class of an input if it's not empty with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap 4.

I have four text inputs, if *any* of the text inputs contain *any* values, i'd like to add a class to a button.

When the button is clicked, I would like to clear the input values, and remove the class from the button.

I have half of it working (clicking button successfully clears all inputs).

My code is below;

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#filterRecords input").on("keyup change", function() {
        $("#filterRecords input").each(function() {
          var element = $(this);
          if (element.val().length > 0) {
            $('#resetFilter').addClass('btn-outline-primary');
          }
        });
      });
      $('#resetFilter').click(function() {
        $('input[type=text]').val('').change();
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row filterRecords">
      <div class="input-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 mb-3">
        <input type="text" id="searchName" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Name">
      </div>
      <div class="input-group col-sm-6 col-md-3 mb-3">
        <input type="text" id="searchLang" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Language">
      </div>
      <div class="input-group col-sm-6 col-md-3 mb-3">
        <input type="text" id="yearMin" class="form-control start" placeholder="Search Start Year">
      </div>
      <div class="input-group col-sm-6 col-md-3 mb-3">
        <input type="text" id="yearMax" class="form-control end" placeholder="Search End Year">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
      <div class="col-md-auto">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" type="button" id="resetFilter">Reset Filters</button>
        <hr>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/johnny_s/20hahn1p/).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: fiddle link? i dont see one

Comment: You seem to have not posted the fiddle link

Comment: Your `filterRecords` is a class not an ID . Prove `<div class="row filterRecords">` and `$("#filterRecords input")` Change this and your code works

Comment: Fiddle link now added sorry!

Comment: @Andreas stop with the copy paste crap he clearly states what he wants

Comment: What's not clear about `When the button is clicked, I would like to clear the input values, and remove the class from the button. I have half of it working (clicking button successfully clears all inputs).`?

Comment: `I have four text inputs, if any of the text inputs contain any values, i'd like to add a class to a button.` and `I have half of it working (clicking button successfully clears all inputs).` implies what he wants and is missing @Andreas

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a reason you aren't using `<input type="reset" />` and are instead re-inventing it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly, `filterRecords` is a class, not an `id`, so your selector is incorrect.

Aside from that, the issue with your logic is that it only ever add the class when the input values change. You also need to have some logic to remove it when no input has a value entered.

You can do that by using `toggleClass()` along with a boolean based on the number of filled inputs, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $inputs = $(".filterRecords input");      
  $inputs.on("input", function() {
    var $filled = $inputs.filter(function() { return this.value.trim().length > 0; });
    $('#resetFilter').toggleClass('btn-outline-primary', $filled.length > 0);
  });
  
  $('#resetFilter').click(function() {
    $inputs.val('').trigger('input');
  });
});
```

```css
.btn-outline-primary {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row filterRecords">
  <div class="input-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 mb-3">
    <input type="text" id="searchName" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Name">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group col-sm-6 col-md-3 mb-3">
    <input type="text" id="searchLang" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Language">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group col-sm-6 col-md-3 mb-3">
    <input type="text" id="yearMin" class="form-control start" placeholder="Search Start Year">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group col-sm-6 col-md-3 mb-3">
    <input type="text" id="yearMax" class="form-control end" placeholder="Search End Year">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row justify-content-md-center">
  <div class="col-md-auto">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" type="button" id="resetFilter">Reset Filters</button>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also note the use of `input` over the combination of `keyup change`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for @Rory McCrossan - thanks for the brilliant explanation too :)

Comment: Unless i am mistaken, change is more reliable on older browsers than input?

Comment: @Deckerz it's supported in everything down to IE9.

Comment: Ah fair enough, i thoguht input was the event that was ie11+

Answer (score -1):

Like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#filterRecords input").on("keyup change", function() {
    $("#filterRecords input").each(function() {
      var element = $(this);
      if (element.val().length > 0) {
        $('#resetFilter').addClass('btn-outline-primary');
      }
    });
  });
  $('#resetFilter').click(function() {
    $("#filterRecords**")[0].reset();
    $(this).removeClass('btn-outline-primary');
  });
});
```

Comment: @pedram I agree that he should add an explanation, but you it's not required that he adds a working demo

Comment: It's ordinary here, a working demo help OP to decide which answer is good, works and etc... @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: And when OP added snippet, it easy to copy snippet and add your own code! that's all